# Skip Certain Test Iterations Using TestNG DataProvider

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, testng-dataprovider

I'm using the TestNG DataProvider to read a datapool.xls file that contains 1017 test cases and 214 columns in a class called ReadData.

I then pass the 214 String parameters into an @Test annotation in a separate class called EnterData.

```
@Test(dataProvider="autodata", dataProviderClass = ReadAutoData.class)
public void autoentry(String Quote, String Garage_Zip, etc...) {
```

I have created a for loop within @Test to only perform the actions for ceratin iterations (say 1-10), which does work by only entering 10 test cases in total. My problem is that at the end of the run it still shows "Total tests run: 1017" instead of only the 10 that actually did anything because of the for loop.

```
// Start for loop for entering auto policies
for (int a = start; a <= end; a++)
{
    if (quote == a)
    {       
        System.out.println("Tier = " + Tier);                       
    } 
}
```

I realize why it shows the total number of tests run as being the entire datapool because it technically passed in and ran through everything in the datapool, I just can't figure out how to only have it show the number of tests that actually ran.

Basically, I'm looking for a way to put the @Test annotation itself in the for loop, possibly?...

Edit:

Here is my current code for reading the datapool in the ReadAutoData Class:

```
@DataProvider(name = "autodata")
public static Object[][] autodata() {
Object[][] arrayObject = getExcelData("C:/dev/AutoDP.xls","NON-COMBO-DP");
return arrayObject;
}

/**
 * @param File Name
 * @param Sheet Name
 * @return
 */
public static String[][] getExcelData(String fileName, String sheetName) {
    String[][] arrayExcelData = null;
    try {
        FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(fs);
        Sheet sh = wb.getSheet(sheetName);

        int totalNoOfCols = sh.getColumns();
        int totalNoOfRows = sh.getRows();

        arrayExcelData = new String[totalNoOfRows-1][totalNoOfCols];

        for (int i= 1 ; i < totalNoOfRows; i++) {

            for (int j=0; j < totalNoOfCols; j++) {
                arrayExcelData[i-1][j] = sh.getCell(j, i).getContents();
            }

        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BiffException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return arrayExcelData;
}
```

Edit 2:

Here's where I'm at so far out of the 1017 test cases, I have gotten it to now show 1007 Skips by adding the following at the beginning of my for loop:

```
// Start for loop for entering auto policies
    for (int a = start; a <= end; a++)
    {
        if (quote < start) throw new SkipException("Testing skip.");
        if (quote > end) throw new SkipException("Testing skip.");

        if (quote == a)
        {

            System.out.println("Starting Iteration = " + Quote);
```

however, it is still showing 1017 Tests run.

Comment: are you okay with showing 10 executed rest skipped ?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am wanting.

Comment: what is stopping you from placing the decision logic for your testiterations into your dataprovider itself, thereby sending only the 10 tests which you want to run?

Comment: Because I'm not exactly sure how to only tell the @DataProvider which rows to grab. I'm currently trying to implement Crazy's method.

Comment: You can have the implementation of sending the Indexes to DataProvider from Test itself. You can check this article https://www.pawangaria.com/post/testng/limit-certain-test-iterations-in-testng-dataprovider/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The only way you can achieve that is to understand how the TestNG framework executes.**

Which means:

1. `SkipException` is not the solution as it will always count all the test cases, even if they are skipped.
2. The number of tests is the number of rows returned by the `@DataProvider` method.

**The solution is then to return the correct number of test cases from the method annotated by `@DataProvider`**:

```
public class ReadAutoData {
    private static int indexFrom;
    private static int indexTo;

    @DataProvider(name = "autodata")
    public static Object[][] autodata() {
        // you should probably cache this into static variable
        Object[][] arrayObject = getExcelData("C:/dev/AutoDP.xls","NON-COMBO-DP"); 

        return java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(arrayObject, indexFrom, indexTo);
    }

    public Class<?> autoDataWithinRange(int from, int to) {
        indexFrom = from;
        indexTo   = to;

        return ReadAutoData.class;
    }
}

@Test(dataProvider="autodata", dataProviderClass = ReadAutoData.autoDataWithinRange(0, 10))
public void autoentry(String Quote, String Garage_Zip, etc...) {
```

This would work if you are not running test concurrently. If you are, you can still use it with small modification using `ThreadLocal`s.

Comment: Well, I've tried implementing this and when trying to pass the dataProviderClass to @Test as you described, I'm getting the following error: "The value for annotation attribute Test.dataProviderClass must be a class literal".

Comment: You are right. In that case you will have to do it a little bit differently, but the point remains the same.

Comment: Got it!!!! Thank you so much for your help. I have learned quite a bit through this. I now have the @DataProvider reading a .properties file to get the iterations to run from the datapool and pass that into the indexFrom (-1) and indexTo and it's working like a dream.

Answer (score 1):

You can always throw TestNG's `SkipException` to mark skipped executions as skipped rather than passed. `SkipException` is a special exception that is not recognized as a failure.

Other that this, you can modify `ReadAutoData.autodata` to return fewer data sets (rows), e.g. only first 10 from your thousands you have in the file.

Comment: I like where you are going, but I guess I cannot figure out how to implement it correctly. When I use the SkipException, it runs through the 10 test cases, however, shows all 1017 skipped. I'm not sure how to get it to load only the test cases I want ran. Say I want to start at 20 and go to 30, etc...

Comment: See Edit 2. I have gotten it to at least show how many tests were skipped now. The problem is it is still showing all 1017 tests as being ran.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating listener class by implementing`IInvokedMethodListener` and implementing method `beforeInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult tr)`  In side that you can take the test result object and get the params and decide what to do for that data set.

```
Object [] params = tr.getParameters();
// put some logic on params and decide
if ( params is something ) {
tr.setStatus(ITestResult.SKIP);
}
```

I am assuming that you want to run or not run based on the params.